# Where to get the positions of the last item in the Listbox (python and tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I write such a simple chatroom and I would like to know how to download the items of the last item in a Listbox because I put all messages in the listbox and I would like that when a message comes from another user, the items will move as if the items will move so that this message is visible.
How to do something like this?

Of course I write in python with the tkinter module :)

Comment: Your question would be better if you provided a simple example of your code and explained, more clearly, what you'd like to happen and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the numerical index of the last item with the documented `index` command, passing in the special string "end":

```
last_index = the_listbox.index("end")
```

To get the value of the last item you can use "end" in the `get` method as well:

```
last_value = the_listbox.get("end")
```

To make sure that the last item in the listbox is visible, you can pass "end" to the `see` method:

```
the_listbox.see("end")
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant the functions see()!

Answer (score 0):

Try

getting the number of items in listbox using
.size()
then do -1 to get the last index
overall,

```
<listbox>.get( <listbox>.size() -1)
```